# Video base application in iOS Swift using Twilio Sdk

Tags: android, ios, iphone, twilio

I made one video call application using Twilio SDK and primary function is working as expected but when two users connected on video at that time one of them kill or terminate the application then opponent video stuck and not disconnected.

so I want to call one API after application will be terminated.

I have tried many ways but after termination, I can't do anything

Any thought ???

Thanks

Comment: You can't call an API after an application terminates, but can you close the call in the pre-termination event (`applicationWillTerminate` in iOS)?

Comment: yeah I have implemented the correct code thanks @philnash